# Truncate Markdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown

I have a Rails site, where the content is written in markdown. I wish to display a snippet of each, with a "Read more.." link.

How do I go about this? Simple truncating the raw text will not work, for example..

```
>> "This is an [example](http://example.com)"[0..25]
=> "This is an [example](http:"
```

Ideally I want to allow the author to (optionally) insert a marker to specify what to use as the "snippet", if not it would take 250 words, and append "..." - for example..

```
This article is an example of something or other.

This segment will be used as the snippet on the index page.

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

This text will be visible once clicking the "Read more.." link
```

The marker could be thought of like an EOF marker (which can be ignored when displaying the full document)

I am using [maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/) for the Markdown processing (RedCloth is very biased towards Textile, BlueCloth is extremely buggy, and I wanted a native-Ruby parser which ruled out peg-markdown and RDiscount)

Alternatively (since the Markdown is translated to HTML anyway) truncating the HTML correctly would be an option - although it would be preferable to not `markdown()` the entire document, just to get the first few lines.

So, the options I can think of are (in order of preference)..

- Add a "truncate" option to the maruku parser, which will only parse the first x words, or till the "excerpt" marker.
- Write/find a parser-agnostic Markdown truncate'r
- Write/find an intelligent HTML truncating function

Comment: redcarpet is a good solution for a parser, just incase. Not a direct answer to this question but since you have mentioned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Write/find an intelligent HTML truncating function

The following from http://mikeburnscoder.wordpress.com/2006/11/11/truncating-html-in-ruby/, with some modifications will correctly truncate HTML, and easily allow appending a string before the closing tags.

```
>> puts "<p><b><a href=\"hi\">Something</a></p>".truncate_html(5, at_end = "...")
=> <p><b><a href="hi">Someth...</a></b></p>
```

The modified code:

```
require 'rexml/parsers/pullparser'

class String
  def truncate_html(len = 30, at_end = nil)
    p = REXML::Parsers::PullParser.new(self)
    tags = []
    new_len = len
    results = ''
    while p.has_next? && new_len > 0
      p_e = p.pull
      case p_e.event_type
      when :start_element
        tags.push p_e[0]
        results << "<#{tags.last}#{attrs_to_s(p_e[1])}>"
      when :end_element
        results << "</#{tags.pop}>"
      when :text
        results << p_e[0][0..new_len]
        new_len -= p_e[0].length
      else
        results << "<!-- #{p_e.inspect} -->"
      end
    end
    if at_end
      results << "..."
    end
    tags.reverse.each do |tag|
      results << "</#{tag}>"
    end
    results
  end

  private

  def attrs_to_s(attrs)
    if attrs.empty?
      ''
    else
      ' ' + attrs.to_a.map { |attr| %{#{attr[0]}="#{attr[1]}"} }.join(' ')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works for me with Textile.

1. Convert it to HTML
2. Truncate it.
3. Remove any HTML tags that got cut in half with

   ```
   html_string.gsub(/<[^>]*$/, "")
   ```
4. Then, uses Hpricot to clean it up and close unclosed tags

   ```
   html_string = Hpricot( html_string ).to_s
   ```

I do this in a helper, and with caching there's no performance issue.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post that helper up here or on gist?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to find a line consisting of nothing but "^" characters:

```
markdown_string = <<-eos
This article is an example of something or other.

This segment will be used as the snippet on the index page.

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

This text will be visible once clicking the "Read more.." link
eos

preview = markdown_string[0...(markdown_string =~ /^\^+$/)]
puts preview
```

Comment: @dbr, thanks for the fix, I was using 's' in irb, but renamed it to something more readable for the post.

Comment: No problem - thanks for the answer! I'll probably use a combination of this with the modified String.truncate_html method

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to truncate the text, why not have 2 input boxes, one for the "opening blurb" and one for the main "guts". That way your authors will know exactly what is being show when without having to rely on some sort of funkly EOF marker.

Comment: That would of course work, but the "opening blurb" is the first part of the post (not a separate description), making the authors duplicate the first part of their post isn't too great a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I will have to agree with the "two inputs" approach, and the content writer would need not to worry, since you can modify the background logic to mix the two inputs in one when showing the full content.

```
full_content = input1 + input2 // perhaps with some complementary html, for a better formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it applies to this case, but adding the solution below for the sake of completeness. You can use strip_tags method if you are truncating Markdown-rendered contents:

```
truncate(strip_tags(markdown(article.contents)), length: 50)
```

Sourced from: 
http://devblog.boonecommunitynetwork.com/rails-and-markdown/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well, the essential part is the code snippet that's in the answer. The link is just the source of the snippet to give credits to the author of the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option that just works:

```
truncate(markdown(item.description), length: 100, escape: false)
```