# Want to show the first 50 or 60 words of a text field in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a stories text field and want to show the first few lines – say the first 50 words of that field – in a snapshot page. How can I do that in Ruby (on Rails)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly the same as [Aaron Hinni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714158/want-to-show-the-first-50-or-60-words-of-a-text-field-in-ruby/714192#714192), but will try and keep 3 full sentences (then truncate to 50 words, if it's the sentences were too long)

```
def truncate(text, max_sentences = 3, max_words = 50)
  # Take first 3 setences (blah. blah. blah)
  three_sentences = text.split('. ').slice(0, max_sentences).join('. ')
  # Take first 50 words of the above
  shortened = three_sentences.split(' ').slice(0, max_words).join(' ')
  return shortened # bah, explicit return is evil
end
```

Also, if this text has any HTML, my answer on ["Truncate Markdown?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395783/truncate-markdown/395814#395814) might be of use

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your words are delimited by a space, you can do something like this.

```
stories.split(' ').slice(0,50).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

In use something very similar in a Rails application to extend ("monkey patch") the base String class.

I created `lib/core_extensions.rb` which contains:

```
class String
  def to_blurb(word_count = 30)
    self.split(" ").slice(0, word_count).join(" ")
  end
end
```

I then created `config/initializers/load_extensions.rb` which contains:

```
require 'core_extensions'
```

Now I have the `to_blurb()` method on all my String objects in the Rails application.