# Removing markdown formatting for quick excerpt

Tags: php, codeigniter, markdown

Anyone know of a script or already built function that will help me create a quick excerpt using already existing markdown formatted content?

I am looking at formatting results like StackOverflow where I have the title, and a short excerpt, for basically news view.  I want to remove the markdown fully and just preserve the few words.

My concern is that I am going to use a codeigniter helper `word_limiter()`to limit the output. Which may create broken markdown:

```
**This is a sentence which has some _markdown_ that is [cutoff..
```

So I'm not sure how to go about it.

All my content is stored with markdown (not HTML formatting) otherwise I would do 'striptags' etc;

I've found something similar for Ruby on SO here: [Truncate Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395783/158014), but I would love something for PHP.

I'm just not sure if I should just strip all `*_[]()>` characters basically? But if there is a URL (split in half), I'm worried it will look nasty.

Thoughts? I've looked around a bit, but at first glance haven't found anything that strips markdown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider marking-up the text, then running strip_tags.

-- Update --

There are a couple of other options, if you do not want to mark-up the text just to strip tags, you can:

1. Introduce a regex to strip out the markdown elements
2. Store the content in the database with NO markup/markdown, just the text
3. If you mark-up then strip_tags, you can store the results in memcache to avoid the extra overhead

Comment: problem is I don't want to process the whole content block, I want to grab only 200 characters (from the DB)

Comment: Are the content blocks that large, where they would actually impact the load time of the page? If you implement pagination, of say 20 - 30 news items I don't think it would be that painful.

Comment: They aren't that big no, but I am trying to make the solution elegant without having to do conversion only to strip tag right after and then shorten the text, it just seems like overkill.

Comment: I'm gonna give it to you as I'm just gonna keep it simple, and you are right, since its not a lot of content, I can grab it, markitdown then strip_tag it, and shorten.  So I've decided to do so.  Thanks!

Comment: For anyone going with the regular expression option, here's a sloppy one I came up with `/(?<=\n|^)\s*(#|\`\`\`([A-Za-z-_]+)?)|((\*{1,2}|_{1,2}|~{2}|\[|\]|\(|\)|\`))/`. The issue is that this will remove all characters like `*` `**` `_` `__` `~~` `[` `]` `(` `)` where they don't have any Markdown role, e.g. `Hello _world` will lose its `_`