# Is there a markdown friendly alternative to "truncatechars:x"?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, markdown

The classic task is to display the list of blog-posts, including a short summary of each post.

As I have seen on the web, the most common approach is to truncate the content of the original blog post.

So my `post_list.html` template looks like this:

```
{% load custom_markdown %}

<div class="col-sm-12">
 <p>
  <small>
   {{ post.text | custom_markdown | truncatechars:160 }}
  </small>
 </p>
</div>
```

If I truncate markdown sometimes the html tags do not get closed properly - the end tag gets truncated - and the whole html page gets all messed-up.

Is there an intelligent way to truncate or do I need to write my own function?

PS The closest I got was this [stackoverflow post: how to truncate markdown  in Ruby/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395783/truncate-markdown).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`truncatechars_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html) tag.

```
{{ post.text | custom_markdown | truncatechars_html:160 }}
```

Comment: Alasdair, this was great! This solved my issue! The html formating is correct, I am not getting the strange line-breaks I used to get minutes ago!
Hehe, actually the blog post list does not look so readable with all the markdown effects, but cosmetics is my job.
Thank you very much indeed!